# How do I get the ISIN of a security from Interactive Brokers?

Tags: python, interactive-brokers

I am trying to get the International Securities Identification Numbers (ISIN) for securities in my Interactive Brokers portfolio.

In the documentation I found two places, that mention *ISIN*:

1. `secId` and `secIdType` fields inside `Contract`: [Source](https://interactivebrokers.github.io/tws-api/classIBApi_1_1Contract.html)
2. `secIdList` field inside `ContractDetails`: [Source](https://interactivebrokers.github.io/tws-api/classIBApi_1_1ContractDetails.html)

But I can't get the API to fill any of these fields. Example code:

```
from ib_insync import *
ib = IB()
ib.connect("127.0.0.1", 4002, 0)
for pfi in ib.portfolio():
    for detail in ib.reqContractDetails(pfi.contract):
        print(detail)
```

This outputs:

```
ContractDetails(summary=Contract(conId=13181, symbol='AEE', secType='STK', exchange='SMART', primaryExchange='NYSE', currency='USD', localSymbol='AEE', tradingClass='AEE'), marketName='AEE', minTick=0.01, orderTypes='ACTIVETIM,ADJUST,ALERT,ALGO,ALLOC,AON,AVGCOST,BASKET,COND,CONDORDER,DARKONLY,DARKPOLL,DAY,DEACT,DEACTDIS,DEACTEOD,DIS,GAT,GTC,GTD,GTT,HID,IBKRATS,ICE,IMB,IOC,LIT,LMT,LOC,MIT,MKT,MOC,MTL,NGCOMB,NODARK,NONALGO,OCA,OPG,OPGREROUT,PEGBENCH,POSTONLY,PREOPGRTH,REL,RPI,RTH,RTHIGNOPG,SCALE,SCALEODD,SCALERST,SMARTSTG,SNAPMID,SNAPMKT,SNAPREL,STP,STPLMT,SWEEP,TRAIL,TRAILLIT,TRAILLMT,TRAILMIT,WHATIF', validExchanges='SMART,AMEX,NYSE,CBOE,ISE,CHX,ARCA,ISLAND,VWAP,DRCTEDGE,NSX,BEX,BATS,EDGEA,CSFBALGO,JEFFALGO,BYX,IEX,CVGXALGO,PSX', priceMagnifier=1, longName='AMEREN CORP', industry='Utilities', category='Electric', subcategory='Electric-Integrated', timeZoneId='EST5EDT', tradingHours='20170816:0400-2000;20170817:0400-2000', liquidHours='20170816:0930-1600;20170817:0930-1600', mdSizeMultiplier=100)
```

As you can see, none of the above mentioned fields are filled. Do you have any idea how to get the ISIN for a security?

Comment: Following your links I found this: For US stocks, receiving the ISIN requires the CUSIP market data subscription (whatever that means)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm working with the **IB API** every day. Therefore I would prefer to get the **ISIN** with the function

`reqFundamentalData`

You have to use 4 arguments and the third is called `reportType`. Here you can choose the easiest type named `ReportSnapshot`. You will receive a `xml`-file and in the second part (`Common Stock`) you find the line with the ISIN. For example in the request for `AAPL`:

`<IssueID Type="ISIN">US0378331005</IssueID>`

It's not so complicated. If you need sample code just ask me.

More informations: [IB about reqFundamentalData](https://interactivebrokers.github.io/tws-api/reuters_fundamentals.html#gsc.tab=0) and [documentation of the function](https://interactivebrokers.github.io/tws-api/classIBApi_1_1EClient.html#abba7df6f72f5516cae4c05c9144a89ee&gsc.tab=0)

Comment: Hi there, I have just seen your answer and would love some advice if possible.  My data source uses ISIN, and I have a hack-job that enables me to locate the corresponding IB symbology, but it only works ~50% of the time so there is a 'dog-work' manual component.  It strikes me that I could scrape all the IB contract details from the website as needed (~once every month or so) and then use logic as you suggest above to obtain all the ISINs, which I could then use to look up the symbols for my stock list.  I also have other questions that I would love to ask, being new to IB's API.

Comment: @Carl - I didn't understand exactly: So, you have many ISINs and you want to find the symbols of IB? But why? You can enter the ISIN in TWS and it automatically enters the right product.
You can describe your goal for the code, ask all the questions here at stackflow or leave me a link where I can contact you. But using stackflow would be the best method to give your questions to the community.

Comment: Yes, I have a file of ISINs that I can load into basket trader, but for many it says the security is not available.  But for those securities, I can manually enter the ISIN in baskettrader and it gives me the option to select the stock, as well as the exchange, but that manual process is time consuming and I have several hundred Isins to go through each month.  Ideally I would automate this whole process. An email address for me is cgrwells@yahoo.co.uk, would love to ask a few related questions to make sure that I don't go down a rabbithole. Thank you

Comment: Solved together with @Carl by loading ticker symbol and creating a csv file with the ticker symbol, ISIN and other data to work with.